# How to show continuity of a function with $n-1$ exponentiations?

Tags: proof-verification, continuity, notation

Say we are given a function $$\Gamma(x)=f_1(x)^{f_2(x)^{\cdot^{\cdot^{f_n(x)}}}}$$

where $f_i,i\in[1;n]$, are continuous functions in their domains. Also assume that the function makes sense, *e.g.,* if $f_n:\Bbb{R\to R},$ then $f_i>0, i \in[1;n-1]$.

Is it fair to say that $\Gamma(x)$ is then also continuous in its domain?

---

First, we note that for $x>0$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ $$x^\alpha=e^{\alpha \ln x}.$$
If $\alpha >0$ and $\beta \in \Bbb{R}$, $$x^{\alpha^\beta}=e^{\alpha^\beta \ln x}=e^{e^{\beta\ln\alpha}\ln x}.$$

Similar pattern works for $\Gamma(x)$. I have already proven the continuity of exponential and logarithm functions. Furthermore, the result

$$\lim_{x\to \xi}g(x)=g\left(\lim_{x\to\xi}x\right)$$

holds if $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=\xi$.

Here I would very much would like to conclude that $\Gamma(x)$ is continuous in its domain. Or, is something missing?

(I  am currently ignoring cases where $f_i<0$ and $f_{i+1}\in \Bbb{Q}$, should such an operation be valid.)

---

**Bonus question**

Sums are conveniently written with Greek capital 'sigma', or $\sum$. For products, the notation is capital 'pi', *i.e*, $\prod$. Is there a similar convention for stepwise exponentiation of exponents, as given above?

Comment: All you need to do is show $f,g$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ $f^g$ continuous, the general result follows by induction.  That follows from $f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)\ln f(x)}$.

Comment: Re: your bonus question, I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) is as close as you'll get to an affirmative answer.

Comment: @Gregory Grant: ... Don't know if this makes sense, but whenever some topic is involved for me, I forget common sense, or in this case, induction.

Comment: @tilper: so $f_i(x) \uparrow n, i \in [1;n]$ is the best option?

Comment: As far as I know, although I wouldn't recommend using such notation in a homework assignment or formal research paper, etc., without explaining it first.  And even then I'd be a little hesitant, personally.

Comment: @LinearChristmas It's just a skill you develop over time like any other, the next time it comes up you'll realize it sooner.  I'm going to go ahead and post my comment as an answer so this question won't linger eternally on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is show $f,g$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ $f^g$ continuous, the general result follows by induction. The basic results follows from  $f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)\ln f(x)}$.